# What is the $1$-norm of the coefficient vector of $f$

Tags: polynomials, normed-spaces

> Given a polynomial $f$, we define $\|f\|_1$ to be the $1$-norm of the coefficient vector of $f$

Can anyone explain to me what this is, and give me an example or a formula to calculate $\|f\|_1$ please?

Comment: If $f=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots +a_0$ is a polynomial with real or complex coefficients $a_k$, then $\|f\|_1:=|a_n|+|a_{n-1}|+\ldots +|a_0|$, where $|\cdot |$ denotes the absolute value of real or complex numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [1-Norm of a Vector](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L1-Norm.html) corresponds to take the sum of the absolute values of its components. Thus, for a polynomial $f(x) = a_d x^d + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0$, we have that the coefficient vector of $f$ is $[a_d ~\cdots ~ a_1 ~a_0 ]^T$ and we have 
$$\| f \|_1 = \sum_{i=0}^d | a_i| = |a_d| + \cdots + |a_1| + |a_0| $$

Comment: Is this definition useful?